# Dependencies issue: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, dependencies, yarn-workspaces

This error is driving me crazy. I'm working with this [repo](https://github.com/animo/simple-demo). For the client side, all good. For the server side, i got this problem:

```
MacBook-Pro$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ tsnd --respawn src/index.ts
[INFO] 20:34:49 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.9.3)
Compilation error in /Users/simple-demo-verifier/server/src/index.ts
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/simple-demo-verifier/server/src/index.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module._compile (/Users/Desktop/simple-demo-verifier/server/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/private/var/folders/9z/40hxmprd3wq40xbpsyfsqq1r0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-13839828883108773.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (/private/var/folders/9z/40hxmprd3wq40xbpsyfsqq1r0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-13839828883108773.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/Users/simple-demo-verifier/server/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
[ERROR] 20:34:49 Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
```

I've already cancelled and cleaned everything (node_modules, package-lock.json etc), but nothing.
Steps to reproduce:

1. Download  the code
2. cd server
3. npm install
4. yarn install
5. yarn dev

Result of npm list:

```
├── @aries-framework/core@0.1.0-alpha.284
├── @aries-framework/node@0.1.0-alpha.284
├── @aries-framework/rest@0.9.4
├── cors@2.8.5
├── express@4.18.2
├── ngrok@4.3.3
├── ts-node-dev@1.1.8
├── ts-node@10.9.1
├── tslog@3.3.4
└── typescript@4.9.3
```

Regarding the error, before that i had some problems with dependencies and i hat to run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` to fix this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: server@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @aries-framework/core@0.1.0-alpha.284
npm ERR! node_modules/@aries-framework/core
npm ERR!   @aries-framework/core@"0.1.0-alpha.284" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @aries-framework/core@"0.1.0-alpha.268" from @aries-framework/rest@0.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@aries-framework/rest
npm ERR!   @aries-framework/rest@"^0.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
```

Comment: Don't you have `docker` installed on your machine?

Comment: What version of `node.js` do you use now?

Comment: The maintainer of this repo said that suggested version for it is 16.8.0, so i'm using this one.

Comment: This is from the server docker file. as you can see, it installs node 12 and `yarn install` runs with no errors! 


`FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
software-properties-common \
    apt-transport-https \
    curl \
    # Only needed to build indy-sdk
    build-essential 

# libindy
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CE7709D068DB5E88
RUN add-apt-repository "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/sdk/deb bionic stable"

# nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/alnDcHw.png You can see both the frontend and backend are built and running correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the issue as the dependencies and platform don't match with the original developer's environment. I had a look at the repo for the server, he used `node.js v12` on `ubuntu 18.04`. Once you have a look at `./server/Dockerfile.demoserver`, you'll get to know more about the environment and build process. You seem to use `macbook pro` at the moment, and if you don't have `docker` installed on your machine, I recommend you to use `codespace` on `GitHub` as I find it very useful. You can use the embedded code editor that is the same as `VS Code`.

I have attached some screenshots to show you how to use it. Got to the repo and:

[image: create your codespace]

[image]

In the terminal, just run `docker-compose up -d` to build the docker image and run the container. When the image is built and the container runs, it will open a new tab automatically to show you the frontend running:

[image]

Comment: Hi there thank you very much for your answer. Everything you said, is correct. But i want to run this on Mac within Node because i'm actually playing around with the code. Therefore i'm not looking for the Dockerized version

Comment: Why don't you install `node12` as I mentioned above? The source is built on node12

Comment: The developer suggested to use node 16.8.0, and in another instance of this project that i've locally, it works with 16.8 too, so it should be the problem here

Comment: You can remove the lockfile, `yarn.lock` and run `yarn install` again

Comment: Did it, not working :(

Comment: What do you see in the terminal?

Comment: Please have a look to the first "code box" i've posted within the question